# Opening a transformation task in Pentaho (Error reading object from XML file)

Tags: pentaho, etl

After I constructed a transformation task in Pentaho spoon, and then saved it as a *.ktr* file.

But an error occurs when I open it, and the error messages are shown below.

To be more specific, this error happens when the task contains a "Hadoop file output" step and occurs on Ununtu only. The tasks on Mac are working fine.

Did anyone encounter this problem and solve it before?

- My Pentaho spoon edition: General Availability Release - 5.4.0.1-130
- My OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Error Messages:

```
Error reading object from XML file

Unable to load step info from XML step nodeorg.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
Unable to load step info from XML
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:92)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main (Spoon.java:654)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start (Spoon.java:9190)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose (Spoon.java:7939)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch (Spoon.java:1319)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent (ActionContributionItem.java:402)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2 (ActionContributionItem.java:490)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection (ActionContributionItem.java:545)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent (Action.java:498)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run (JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100 (JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke (AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke (AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke (AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile (Spoon.java:4159)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile (Spoon.java:4222)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile (Spoon.java:4550)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.TransFileListener.open (TransFileListener.java:51)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML (TransMeta.java:2977)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepMeta.<init> (StepMeta.java:307)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutputMeta.loadXML (TextFileOutputMeta.java:628)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutputMeta.readData (TextFileOutputMeta.java:693)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.hadoopfileoutput.HadoopFileOutputMeta.loadSource (HadoopFileOutputMeta.java:97)


Unable to load step info from XML
 at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:92)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main (Spoon.java:654)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start (Spoon.java:9190)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose (Spoon.java:7939)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch (Spoon.java:1319)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent (null:-1)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent (ActionContributionItem.java:402)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2 (ActionContributionItem.java:490)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection (ActionContributionItem.java:545)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent (Action.java:498)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run (JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100 (JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke (AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke (AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
 at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke (AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile (Spoon.java:4159)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile (Spoon.java:4222)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile (Spoon.java:4550)
 at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.TransFileListener.open (TransFileListener.java:51)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML (TransMeta.java:2977)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepMeta.<init> (StepMeta.java:307)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutputMeta.loadXML (TextFileOutputMeta.java:628)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutputMeta.readData (TextFileOutputMeta.java:693)
 at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.hadoopfileoutput.HadoopFileOutputMeta.loadSource (HadoopFileOutputMeta.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be related to [this](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-14077) open issue on Pentaho's Jira.

Try to isolate the problem by un-checking *Accept filename from field* checkbox and see whether it solves it or not. If it's indeed the problem, then try to find another way to pass on the file name(s) to the input step until a fix is released (RegExp from variables would be one option).

[image: Picture for illustration]

Comment: Would you please show me where I can un-check the _Accept filename from field_ checkbox?

Comment: Absolutely, double click on the Hadoop File Input step in your transformation => Stay on the `File` tab =>  Look down the dialog for a checkbox called `Accept filenames from previous step` and un-check it. If you like working with the transformations' XML, look for the `<accept_filenames>` tag and set it to `<accept_filenames>N</accept_filenames>`

Comment: The answer doesn't solve my problem since the checkbox, `Accept filenames from previous step`,  is always un-checked in my broken file, but the link in the answer definitely gives me some information to my problem. Thanks!